# grep an empty value in a binary file in linux

Tags: linux, grep, binaryfiles

I have a binary file in Linux machine with values: `AB=^]` (`^]` is an empty value), AB=N and AB=Y. I want to get the count of occurrences of `AB=^]` in the file.

I am using the following command :

```
zcat Logfile|grep 'AB=^]' |wc -l
```

but it gives the count 0. The above command works fine for AB=N and Y so I guess I am searching for wrong pattern, what should I search for if not `AB=^]` ?

Output for the above command:

```
gzip: Logfile: unexpected end of file

0
```

here 0 indicates the number of occurrences of tag AB=^]

Comment: What does `colortracer.pl` do with the output? Can you pipe it to `cat -v` of `xxd` and add the output here?

Comment: I have edited the question .even without the colortracer.pl the command works exactly as expected , it just gives a colored output with highlighted sections

Comment: Is `^]` two literal characters in the binary file? Or is it a single character?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the deleted answers should work. Except of escaping the `^` and `]` your regex, you can also use their hexadecimal notation:

```
grep -o 'AB='$'\x5E'$'\x5D' file | wc -l
```

Comment: I tried this : grep -o 'AB='$'\x5E'$'\x5D' Logfile| wc -l , but still gives count 0

Comment: Then you did not described your problem properly. There is no magic, if the text contains the sequence `AB=^]` it will work, otherwise the text does not contain that sequence. Using a hex-editor you should be able to find that out.